# Make Preview automatically reload PDF without switching to it

Tags: pdf, preview

If I change the contents of a PDF file that is open in Preview, it automatically reloads it when I switch to the program.  Is there a way to make it do this without explicitly switching to the program?

The reason is that I am writing LaTeX, and I would like to see the updated PDF, but switching between Preview and back is a little annoying each time.  For now, I have a line in my Makefile that just does

```
open $(FILEPREFIX).pdf
open -a iTerm
```

every time it builds the document (I use emacs in the terminal as my text editor), but even this is a little annoying, especially since I would like to write a hook in emacs that automatically builds the document at regular intervals, and this would cause it to jump away from the editor.

P.S. I know that Skim can do this.  But I've found its autoupdating to be unreliable (i.e., sometimes it just stops doing it altogether, and I have to manually reload the document; if someone knows how to fix that, I would appreciate that as well).

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/232067/preview-app-only-auto-refreshes-if-you-alt-tab-to-it) is the only I've found. I think Skim works well, I don't have any problem (if you explain what is exactly what happens to you I'll try to help).

Comment: I think the issue with Skim might have something to do with the file being updated too fast.  I run `latex` two or three times in the Makefile to get the references right, and by the time Skim reads it from the first update, it has already been updated a second time.  But that's just a guess (it usually works, but invariably, at some point it will stop working until I refresh manually).

Comment: Also, the "updating" dialog that pops up in Skim is a little annoying, especially with running `latex` several times per make.

Comment: Check [Scribo](http://www.scriboapp.com/) too.

Comment: Can Scribo work just as a PDF viewer?  I appreciate that it's nice for editing LaTeX, but believe me, nothing can beat Emacs + AuCTeX.

Answer (score 3):

I have never had problems with Skim not being able to keep up, but I use [latex-makefile](https://code.google.com/p/latex-makefile/) which generates temporary PDFs under other names until the very last pass. Perhaps you could try using that and see if it works, or adjusting your own Makefile similarly?

Comment: Good idea.  It should be a trivial change to make it do this.